# rspec carrierwave should have_dimensions fails always: thumb not resized

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, minimagick

I have carrierwave set up and it processes my images fine. I get nicely resized thumb versions in a subfolder and all that. Both from my frontend (HTML) and from my `rails console`. I use MiniMagic

But in my rspec the thumb test fails always.

```
describe 'processed images' do
  before(:each) do
    AttachmentUploader.enable_processing = true
    AttachmentUploader.enable_processing = true
    @uploader = AttachmentUploader.new(@post, :image)
    @uploader.store!(File.open(@file))
  end

  after(:each) do
    @uploader.remove!
    AttachmentUploader.enable_processing = false
  end

  describe 'the thumb version' do
    it "should scale down ane image to be exactly 50 by 50 pixels" do
      @uploader.recreate_versions!
      @uploader.thumb.should have_dimensions(50, 50)
    end
  end
```

`@file` is a file found in fixtures. It is found and attached (other tests pass). And if I comment out the line `@uploader.remove!`, It leaves a file in e.g. `.../public/uploads/post/image/thumb_fig.png`. 
That file, however is *not* resized. When invoking the same sequence trough `rails console` it gets resized just fine.

Am I missing something in my specs? Do I need to set a special flag? Force a certain method to be ran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a little late to this party but working on something similar myself.  From what I can tell your test looks fine although I believe @uploader.recreate_Versions! is unnecessary.  Otherwise check to make sure that you do have a call to process in your Uploader class and that you 
`include CarrierWave::Test::Matchers` in your tests

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled processing for Carrierwave in `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`.

It should read:

```
config.enable_processing = true
```

Comment: This will slow down all tests, it's better to make the uploaders process files in the test where is needed rather than everywhere.